# SELinux sandbox on debian buster

Tags: debian, selinux, sandbox

I have installed and enabled SELinux on Debian 10 (Buster). Running `sandbox` however returns:

```
/usr/bin/sandbox: Sandbox Policy is not currently installed.
You need to install the selinux-policy-sandbox package in order to run this command
```

There are, however, no packaged named `selinux-policy-sandbox package` the repo and `semodule -l` does not list any modules names `sandbox`.

What now?

Comment: you could try and get the centos version and extract its .pp file

Comment: @A.B thanks. Do you know why this is not already included in Debian?

Comment: I assume the development is mostly done at RedHat and this might have been something missed. OR I did miss something and it's available elsewhere at Debian.